# How to change span text than in the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using double click on the `img`

This code

```
$("#insert-zone").on("dblclick", ">div>img", function(){
 console.log($(this).parentNode.className(spanDefCat));

 var answer = confirm ("Set Defaul Cat to " +$("#txt_CategoryID").val()+"?")
    if (answer){....
```

.

This is the div item

```
<div class="item-container cart-item sameCat">
   <div class="SetDefault">
      <img border="0" title="Carrie Style Silver Name Necklace" src="medium_101-01-071-02.jpg" alt="1102">
      <div class="item-header">
         <div class="item-body">
            <ul class="item-ul">
               <li>
                  <span class="spanDefCat">DefaultCat: 32</span>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-footer"></div>
</div>
```

When I double click the img, I need to go back to parent `cart-item` than contains `li` with span class `spanDefCat` like you see it in code  and change  the `DefaulCat` to `80` or what ever I need to change the span.

full Html

```
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
    <ol id="insert-zone" class="ui-droppable ui-sortable">
    <div class="item-container cart-item sameCat">
    <div class="item-container cart-item ">
    <div class="item-container cart-item sameCat">
    <div class="item-container cart-item sameCat">
   </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can use `$('.spanDefCat').html('80');`

Comment: does this `>div>img` selector works ?

Comment: does this >div>img selector works ? on click yes

Comment: @VovaPotapov You can use `@User` to reply to someone in the comments.

Comment: You can use $('.spanDefCat').html('80');? No i have a lots of other items that have this class i need to change only my parent class .spanDefCat to 80 and this one is change  all classes

Comment: Your html is improperly nested (one missing `</div>`). Please show us the actual markup, if possible also including the `#insert-zone` element. Currently it looks as your selector won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$(this).parent().find('.spanDefCat').html($("#txt_CategoryID").val())`

This will change the value of all `.spanDefCat` in the parent of the image.

Comment: this is 100% what i was looking for thx to all especially you @Daniel Kurz

Answer (score 0):

Add this code inside .on function

```
var newCatVal = "DefaultCat: "+$("#txt_CategoryID").val();
$(this).closest('.cart-item').find(".spanDefCat").text(newCatVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that does what you want:

```
$(function(){
    $("img").dblclick(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".spanDefCat").each(function(){
            $(this).text("DefaultCat: 80");
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrA8E/